# How to display fields horizontally in a node?

Tags: entities, nodes

A node lists all its field vertically one after the other by default. Does anyone know of a way to display at least some of the fields horizontally?

Like so:

```
FIELD 1               FIELD 2              FIELD 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css for that.You can aligned them horizontally using the float:left css property or may be you can use the display suite module for this.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of Drupal's field display is to wrap the content in DIVs, which are displayed as block-level elements by default, hence, one per line.

There are a number of different ways to solve for your display needs.

As Sidharth mentioned, displaying fields can be done via custom CSS. Typically you'd want to create a custom node.tpl.php for your theme and apply your CSS rules to those elements in your template.

Another solution, if you're not looking for custom templates for different node types, is the [Field Group Inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_inline) module.

Comment: thanks! Also thanks to SIdharth. I just used float with some margin padding. That worked well. I guess I had dismissed that as a possibility, thinking there might be a more difficult way to do it for some reason. Thanks again.